# Consecutive Material-UI Snackbars (with React-Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, react-functional-component

Instead of having many snackbars scattered throughout many components I refactored my app to have one single custom component that gets called with Redux to display any variation of a snackbar that it needs to.

**Expected behaviour:**

When a call to show a second snackbar is made, the current snack bar animates out smoothly and the new one animates in, like in the [Material-UI official example](https://material-ui.com/components/snackbars/#consecutive-snackbars).

**Current behaviour:**

Currently if a snackbar is called while another is open it just replaces the content of the existing snackbar. Because no new snackbar is made this can easily result in the new snack message disappearing a moment later, not giving the user time to read the new message.

[image: Edit Consecutive Material-UI Snackbars]

I tried copying the code from the official MUI example linked above and got close, but couldn't get it to work perfectly smoothly. `MyAttempt.jsx` is this attempt. `Demo.jsx` is the code before this attempt, and displays the current behaviour described above.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, the problem in your case is the double `useEffect` you use to manage `snackPack` in `MyAttempt` component. When you call `onShowSnackbar` from `App.jsx`, you are changing `snackData` to show new snack content. But on this moment, this useEffect will be fired:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    setSnackPack((prev) => [...prev, { snackData, key: new Date().getTime() }]);
}, [snackData]);
```

this one changes the Snack content and you see for a second the new snack content. Then this other useEffect will be fired:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (snackPack.length && !messageInfo) {
      // Set a new snack when we don't have an active one
      setMessageInfo({ ...snackPack[0] });
      setSnackPack((prev) => prev.slice(1));
      setOpen(true);
    } else if (snackPack.length && messageInfo && open) {
      // Close an active snack when a new one is added
      setOpen(false);
    }
  }, [snackPack, messageInfo, open]);
```

This one closes the old snack and re-open the new one. That's the cause of flickering.

To avoid this, it's necessary to set `messageInfo` to `undefined` just before set the new snackPack. So change the first useEffect in this way:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    setMessageInfo(undefined);   // set messageInfo to undefined
    setSnackPack((prev) => [...prev, { snackData, key: new Date().getTime() }]);
  }, [snackData]);
```

and the flickering disappears.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/consecutive-material-ui-snackbars-forked-hkr3h?file=/src/MyAttempt.jsx) your codesandbox modified.

Comment: thank but this still leaves a small flicker, its reduced the time dramatically but it is still changing the contents of the first snack before it fades out. its very quick but its still there, unlike the official example

Comment: this also stops the `else if` block in the second useEffect from ever getting run because it makes `snackPack.length && messageInfo && open` never true (can check this with console logs)

Answer (score -1):

I just have to add to Giovanni Esposito that adding setMessageInfo(undefined) to  onClose function worked for me.